Scipy lowpass filter amplifies noisefloor in stopband
I´m trying to simulate digital signals using numpy and scipy.
When trying to lowpass filter a signal of the sines the result appears to amplify the region between the frequency spikes above the level before the filter. Even in the stop band.
Am I missing something essential here, because this doesn´t seem to be logical to me?
As far as my understanding goes a filter can at best pass a frequency through as is but not amplify it.
I´m using a 5th degree butterworth filter with a cutoff at 40 Hz filtering a signal made up of 10, 30 and 70 Hz at a sampling rate of 200 Hz with 200 data points.
Here is the MWE im using:
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import windows, butter, sosfiltfilt, sosfreqz
from scipy.fft import rfft, rfftfreq
    
SAMP_RATE = 200

TIME = np.arange(0, SAMP_RATE) / SAMP_RATE

WINDOW = windows.hamming(SAMP_RATE, True)

FREQS = rfftfreq(SAMP_RATE, 1/SAMP_RATE)

FILTER = butter(5, 40, output="sos", fs=SAMP_RATE)

orig = np.sin(2*np.pi*10*TIME)+np.sin(2*np.pi*30*TIME)+np.sin(2*np.pi*70*TIME)

orig_ft = 10*np.log10(np.abs(rfft(orig*WINDOW)))

filtered = sosfiltfilt(FILTER, orig)

filtered_ft = 10*np.log10(np.abs(rfft(filtered*WINDOW)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_ylabel("Relative Gain [dB]")
ax.set_xlabel("Frequency [Hz]")

filter_freq, filter_response = sosfreqz(FILTER, fs=SAMP_RATE)
filter_response = 10*np.log10(np.abs(filter_response))
ax.plot(filter_freq, filter_response, label="Filter Response")

ax.plot(FREQS, orig_ft, label="Original signal")
ax.plot(FREQS, filtered_ft, label="Filtered signal")

ax.legend(loc="lower left")

plt.show()

This is the spectrum generated by the code:

I would expect the green line being always below the orange one in the stop band.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Isn't that just spectral leakage from the Hamming window?  Blackman-Harris shows the tones better, for instance:

Also the sym parameter should be False for spectral analysis:

